# how to remove cache from http get reqest on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I am working on node js web application and I am doing a http get request which address a db and takes data via query.

The http get request is working fine on chrome but on IE each get is not updated but returned from some sort of cache. That makes the result of the db query to be not updated (beacuse it is taken from chache).

I can see that it is being taken from chache form F12 developer tool in IE:

[image]

My code below. I know that I should add something like:

```
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

to my request but I think that I maybe put this line in the wrong place beacuse the get reuqest still taken from chache and gives me bad result...

client

```
$http.get('/users')

.success(function(data) {
    $scope.usersNumber = data.length;

})
.error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

server

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
    get_user(req, res);
});

var get_user= function(req, res){

   var query= User_session.find();
   query.exec( function(err, docs){
      res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");

      res.json(docs);
        //mongoose.connection.close();

    });  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding max-age to your header:

```
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma:no-cache
```

The response that you captured from the developer tools shows that the response is picked from cache. The cached response had a expires header which specified the duration for which the response can be picked from cache and is not considered stale.

You would want to include a no-cache directive for End-to-end reload

> The request includes a "no-cache" cache-control directive or, for
>   compatibility with HTTP/1.0 clients, "Pragma: no-cache". Field names
>   MUST NOT be included with the no-cache directive in a request. The
>   server MUST NOT use a cached copy when responding to such a request.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

You can also try this another solution to force client reloads. Add a query string parameter to your url. 
Eg: If you have a /users, instead make the url as /users?uniqstamp=<timestamp>

Your browser always thinks that the entire path including the query string makes a URL. so you will always get a 200 ok that is served fresh. Make sure that timestamp that you use is from javascript time in millis so that the timestamp is always unique.

Comment: thanks, tried it but I am still getting results from chache

Comment: I updated with the Pragma: no-cache for HTTP/1.0 clients.

Comment: Did it work? I also added another technique to prevent caching.